# Default Method in Interface - Java

Tags: java, methods, interface, default

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IEntityParam {

    public void validateParam(Object object);

    public default void validateParam(Object object,List<String> Str){
        validateParam(object);
    }
}
```

Suppose `IEntityParam` is very old interface extended by many classes and I need  new method in it. I have added a new method in with another parameter. 
But my default implementation doesn't use new parameter List in its default method. Technically, there is no problem. But is it correct use of default method?  Or Should I keep this new method to specific class as I am not using second parameter in default implementation.

**Note :** The list of String which is supplied here is used in just one implementation right now but can be used in other implementation in future. It is not very specific and can be used by other implementation as well.

Comment: As far as *`IEntityParam` is concerned*, this default method has no point.

Comment: I'd rather create another class with the new method `validateParam(Object object,List<String> Str)` and extend this class wherever I need to use its new method. Instead of modifying the existing Interface which is already being used at many places as you mentioned.

Comment: adding to @ernest_k it's very confusing and misleading

Comment: It's a dirty workaround for the fact that you don't want to change multiple classes due to a new interface, but a workaround that does its work is as good as it can be. I'd rather adjust all classes to the new (relevant) method than doing it this way cause refactoring code is one of the big advantages of modern IDE but that's just personal opinion.

Comment: To answer your question, I need to see how this interface is *used* after this refactoring. i.e. how do you decide which of the two methods to call on a given instance?

Comment: I agree. The statement "Default methods are known to facilitate backward compatibility when interfaces/contracts evolve with new methods" makes it clear for me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a misuse of default methods. Default methods are known to facilitate backward compatibility when interfaces/contracts evolve with new methods, but the problem in your case is that not all `IEntityParam` implementations care about the new version of the "contract". Default methods are conceptually part of the interface's contract.

The normal way to address your current need is to extend the interface:

```
public interface IEntityParam {
    public void validateParam(Object object);
}

public interface IEntityParamExtended extends IEntityParam {
    public default void validateParam(Object object,List<String> Str);
}
```

This way, your class that needs the second method will implement `IEntityParamExtended` and provide an implementation for both methods; while all other implemnetations of `IEntityParam` remain unaffected.

In the future, when `IEntityParamExtended` needs to be promoted to `IEntityParam` (i.e., when the new method forms part of the `IEntityParam` contract), you can use a `default` method to avoid forcing all existing implementations to be changed and recompiled.